# How to create 2 columns in a dataframe from one zip

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I wish to turn the zips in the 3rd columns into 2 different columns with either number as seen in df2, how would I do this?

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
data = pd.DataFrame(([[1, 2, (3,5)], [4, 5, (6,4)], [7, 8, (9,1)]]), columns = ['a', 'b', 'c and d'])
print (data)
```

the desired output:

```py
data2 = pd.DataFrame(([[1, 2, 3,5], [4, 5, 6,4], [7, 8, 9,1]]), columns = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'])
print(data2)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can `pop` the column so it's removed and then use the `DataFrame` constructor on the list of tuples. Join the results.

```
res = pd.concat([data, pd.DataFrame(data.pop('c and d').tolist(), columns=['c', 'd'])], axis=1)

   a  b  c  d
0  1  2  3  5
1  4  5  6  4
2  7  8  9  1
```

---

More straight-forward, you can assign the elements of the tuples with the Series.str accessor, then delete the column.

```
data['c'] = data['c and d'].str[0]
data['d'] = data['c and d'].str[1]
data = data.drop(columns='c and d')
```

Answer (score 1):

Another solution:

```
data[["c", "d"]] = data["c and d"].apply(pd.Series)
data = data.drop(columns="c and d")
print(data)
```

Prints:

```
   a  b  c  d
0  1  2  3  5
1  4  5  6  4
2  7  8  9  1
```